# How to install pyzmq for python's virtual environment in MacOs?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, apple-m1, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment in python for my project. I wanted to use the virtual environment's kernel in jypyter-lab. All the instructions in the internet tells me to install jupyter package in my virtual environment. While installing it, it tries to install pyzmq package and fails with the error message:

```
buildutils/initlibzmq.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit code 1
```

Can somebody help me fix this issue? I am new to python and I have already scoured a lot of post in stackoverflow. If someone has already answered a working solution in other posts, please redirect me to that post.

Commands used:

```
$source ./venv/bin/activate

# for installing jupyter
$python -m pip install juypter

# only trying to install pyzmq
$python -m pip install pyzmq
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What command are you using to install?

Comment: I have updated the post with the commands that I've used from activating the virtual environment to installing the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, something to do with Py3.11 on Mac M1.
I switched to latest Python 3.10 and could install pyzmq.

```bash
# When using Poetry:
cd project # with pyproject.toml 
poetry env use 3.10
poetry install

# When using Homebrew, since we have an issue on MacOs
brew install python@3.10
brew link python@3.10

pip install pyzmq
```